# How to display common Column values from three different tables from sql server ms

Tags: sql, sql-server

INSERT INTO SOC(Phone,Network,Place)
VALUES(8934,'Landline','Miyapur'), (8962,'Jio','Miyapur'), (9033,'voda','Miyapur'), (9032,'Bsnl','Miyapur')

Insert INTO SOC_1(Phone,Network,Place)
VALUES(8934,'Airtel','SRNagar'), (9052,'Jio','SRNagar'), (1000,'voda','SRNagar'), (2000,'Bsnl','SRNagar')

insert INTO SOC_2(Phone,Network,Place)
VALUES(9052,'jio','kutply'), (9033,'voda','kutply'), (8934,'Airtel','kutply'), (3000,'Bsnl','kutply')

---

I want to diaply all the duplicate results in the result pane as

Phone   Place
8934    Miyapur
8934    SRNAGAR
8934    kutply
9052    SRNagar
9052    kutply
9033    Miyapur
9033    kutply

I tried using

```
SELECT SOC.Phone, SOC_1.Network, SOC_2.Place
FROM SOC
JOIN SOC_1 ON SOC.Phone = SOC_1.Phone
JOIN SOC_2 ON SOC_1.Phone = SOC_2.Phone
GROUP BY SOC.Phone, SOC_1.Network, SOC_2.Place
```

but getting only 1 result as

8934   Airtel   Miyapur

Comment: Whats the result you are getting?

Comment: Images of data *don't* help us help you. Take the time to post it in a consumable format; preferably DDL and DML statements. Don't forget your expected results as well, and an explanation of the problem. Also, why do you have a `GROUP BY` when you have no aggregation?

Comment: i am getting result as   8934 | Miyapur

Comment: Yes - because `8934` is the **only** number that is present in **all three tables** - what did you expect??

Comment: marc_s , i want to display all the duplicates in result Pane as
8934|miyapur
8934|SRNagar
8934|kuktply

like this i want

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your group by clause. So just:

```
SELECT SOC.Phone, SOC_1.Network, SOC_2.Place
FROM SOC
JOIN SOC_1 ON SOC.Phone = SOC_1.Phone
JOIN SOC_2 ON SOC_1.Phone = SOC_2.Phone
```

Then take a look at some [group by documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-group-by.htm).

Comment: Tried but getting as   8934 Miyapur

Comment: From your query, you should be receiving three columns. My guess would be that your `Network` and `Place` columns are empty. Try doing a simple `SELECT Network FROM SOC_1 WHERE SOC.Phone = <a value from SOC>`.

Comment: Kyle  , I am getting result as 8934 | Airtel | Miyapur

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this one. Try it out

```
SELECT s.Phone, s.Place
FROM SOC s
OUTER APPLY 
(
     SELECT Phone from SOC_1
     UNION 
     SELECT Phone from SOC_2
)T WHERE T.Phone = s.Phone

UNION ALL

SELECT s1.Phone, s1.Place
FROM SOC_1 s1
OUTER APPLY 
(
     SELECT Phone from SOC
     UNION 
     SELECT Phone from SOC_2
)T WHERE T.Phone = s1.Phone

UNION ALL

SELECT s2.Phone, s2.Place
FROM SOC_2 s2
OUTER APPLY 
(
     SELECT Phone from SOC
     UNION 
     SELECT Phone from SOC_1
)T WHERE T.Phone = s2.Phone
```